# What do we take as the energy scale in the $\beta$ function/ running coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, renormalization

So when we renormalise a qft we usually find that the renormalised parameters depend on some energy scale  $\mu$.

What explicitly is this energy scale?  Is it just the COM energy of that given internal vertex (however this would have the problem that you also need to integrate the coupling strength when you integrate over the undetermined loop momenta) or is it the COM energy of the whole system (ie com of the two incoming external legs)?

Comment: Most generally, the parameter $\mu$ is *defined* as the scale you've used to define renormalized parameters or couplings, nothing more or less. The fact that its definition is so arbitrary is why you can write $dg_B/d\mu = 0$ for all bare parameters $g_B$, which is what leads to RG equations.

Comment: ok, so this means we don't integrate over the momentum dependence of the coupling constant - thats nice and what I thought.

However, lets say I do some experiments and use these to renormalise the theory (in a given scheme, say MS or something) and have numerical values for the renormalised masses, coupling strengths etc.  Then I want to do another experiment, at an arbitrary energy, can i use the values I just 'measured'?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that once you've input measurements for the coupling constants at a given energy scale, you can then predict experimental values at other energy scales using your earlier measurements.